# flutter custom height textfield with suffix icon

Tags: flutter

How can I create a custom height text field with a suffix icon? Right now the TextField I created has alignment issues, i.e the text and suffix icon is not aligned equally:

```
  Widget _buildPassInput(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 45,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: CustomColors.primary,
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: _passController,
          cursorColor: CustomColors.primary,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          style: CustomTexts.search,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          autofocus: false,
          obscureText: _obscureText,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Password",
            hintStyle: CustomTexts.search,
            border: InputBorder.none,
            isDense: true,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            suffix: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                });
              },
              child: Icon(
                _obscureText ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                color: CustomColors.primary,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The default TextField height was not working for me so I need to create a custom one. The suffix icon is centered but the text is showing a little below center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you.I have add it `prefixIcon` also if you dont need then remove `prefixIcon` code

Refer `TextFormField` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html)

Refer `InputDecoration` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)

declare bool variable:

```
bool obsecureText = true;
```

Create function for show and hide password:

```
void showPassword() {
    setState(() {
      obsecureText = !obsecureText;
    });
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
TextFormField(
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Password Required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      obscureText: obsecureText,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          onPressed: showPassword,
          icon: Icon(
            obsecureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
          ),
        ),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.vpn_key,
        ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Password',
        hintText: 'Enter Password Here',
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: thanks but is it possible to do it inside a custom height?

Comment: @FahimHoque you want to like textArea TextFormfield?

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputBorderDecoration = OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black));

    double textHeight = 40;

    // define a width if you want, or let the constrains of the parent define it.
    double inputWidth = double.infinity;

    return Center(
      child: Container(
          width: inputWidth,
          height: textHeight,
          color: Colors.green.withOpacity(.2),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(text: 'hello world'),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: textHeight),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    enabledBorder: inputBorderDecoration,
                    focusedBorder: inputBorderDecoration,
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(.5),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              FittedBox(
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => print("touch button"),
                  child: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
```